# Hive Query: defining a variable which is a list of strings

Tags: sql, hive, hql

How can I create a constant list and use it in the WHERE clause of my query?

For example, I have a hive query, where I say

```
Select t1.Id,
       t1.symptom
from t1
WHERE lower(symptom) NOT IN ('coughing','sneezing','xyz', etc,...)
```

Instead of keep repeating this long list of symptoms (which makes the code very ugly), is there a way to define it ahead of time as

MyList = ('coughing','sneezing','x',...)

and then in WHERE clause I'd just say WHERE lower(symptom) not in MyList.

Comment: You can put the list in a table and use `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the list in a table and use `join`:

```
Select t1.Id, t1.symptom
from t1
where lower(symptom) NOT IN (select symptom from mysymptoms_list);
```

This persists the list, so it can be used in multiple queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hive variable to do this.

```
SET hivevar:InClause=('coughing','sneezing','x',...)
```

Make sure you don't leave spaces either side of equals.

```
SELECT t1.Id,
       t1.symptom
 FROM  t1
WHERE LOWER(symptom) NOT IN ${InClause}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with joins, you can use a left join with where clause:

```
Select t1.Id, t1.symptom  
from
t1 A left join MyList B 
on 
lower(A.symptom) = lower(B.symptom)
where lower(B.symptom) IS NULL;
```

This query will retain all symptoms(A.symptom) from table `t1` in one column and for the second column(B.symptom) corresponding to the table `MyList`, the value will be same as the symptom in t1 if a match is found or NULL if a match is not found.

You want those where a match is not found, hence the where clause.